# How do I specify UTF-8 (or another encoding) for jQuery's $.serialize() method?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, utf-8, struts

Several places in my employer's web app use jQuery/ajax to submit a form and display the results. Most of them use `$(form).serialize()` to convert the form's contents to a single string. The problem is, with characters like `é õ á`, they get encoded in a different format than elsewhere in the app. When I call `$(form).serialize()`, `Test é õ á` in the "name" field gets converted to `name=Test+%C3%A9+%C3%B5+%C3%A1`

I want to specifically serialize the form's values as a UTF-8 string instead of whatever is currently being used. Is there a way to specify encoding for `serialize()`, or do I need to submit a different way?

EDIT:

From Pointy's comment, it sounds like it's url encoding rather than jquery/javascript/ajax doing it. If that's the case, I may need an option that takes the url encoded string and sorts it back out on the Java end. We're using Struts + Tomcat. Any suggestions?

Comment: JavaScript strings are **always** UTF-16. What you're seeing is URL encoding results.

Comment: The url encoded string can be decoded on the receiver using a corresponding decoder.